# Direct sum of submodules and uniqueness

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm having difficulties solving this problem.

Let $K\oplus K'$ and $L\oplus L'$ be direct sums of submodules of $M$ such that $K \oplus K' = L\oplus L'$. Show that $K=L$ does not necessarily imply $K' = L'$.

So $K\oplus K' = K\oplus L'$, and wouldn't this mean that for every element $k+k'\in K\oplus K'$ there exists exactly one element $k+l'\in K\oplus L'$ such that $k+k' = k+l'$, and vice versa? I don't see how this can mean anything else than $K'=L'$, but I might have misunderstood direct sums. Any help/tips is much appreciated

Comment: The $k$ in $k + k'$ isn't necessarily the same $k$ in $k + l'$. Try constructing an example using infinite direct sums.

Comment: Hint: Consider the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ with subspace $K = \langle(1,0)\rangle$. Note that any $1$-dimensional subspace not equal to $K$ will form a direct sum with $K$ that gives the entire space.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Infinite direct sums seems like a bad place to start for this, as it does not need to be nearly so complicated.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft If I consider $K = \langle(1,0)\rangle$, $K' = \langle(1,1)\rangle$,  $L' = \mathbb{R}^{2}$, then $K\oplus K' = \mathbb{R}^{2} = K\oplus L'$, but $K' \neq L'$. Would this be a sufficient proof?

Comment: Not quite. Your $L'$ does not form a direct sum with $K$ since it does not intersect it trivially.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft What if I let $L' = \langle(0,1)\rangle$ instead? I'm having a hard time understanding the exact properties of direct sums. I'll ask my prof. tomorrow about this exercise.

Comment: Right, your new example works perfectly.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Great! Thanks a lot for the help <3